# New taskbar icon when opening a window in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, taskbar

I have an application that opens another window on some action. I have set a separate icon for the new window, and a new item appears in the taskbar, but the item is stacked behind the original app window. Is it possible to show the new window unstacked in the task bar? So I would have 2 icons in the task bar.

Please see the image for my problem.

[image]

Comment: This is a Windows option. You can't force it. Unless you start your second window in another process, I guess.

Comment: read this article : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/dd942846.aspx (Figure 3 ...)

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to Xaruth for pointing me in the right direction I found the answer. It seems widows uses an `ApplicationID` to determine if a window should be grouped with another one.

If you download the Windows API Code Pack you can set the `ApplicationID` of the window you want to appear as a separate taskbar icon.

Here's the code:

```
TaskbarManager.Instance.SetApplicationIdForSpecificWindow(
    new WindowInteropHelper(wind).Handle, "Gx3OptimisationWindow");
```

Where wind is the window you want as a separate icon and `GX3OptimisationWindow` is the new `ApplicationID`.

Comment: Im trying this on windows 10, I cannot find the bit of code you have put above in that article, where you have `wind` i have put my window name and it says value does not fall within the range. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @TristanRead The reason that you received this error is because your window doesn't have a handle yet. Try calling window.Show() before calling this code.

Comment: @TristanRead Or for winforms put it in the form Constructor. For WPF you need to put it in the SourceInitialized Event.