# MFC app - Class library WPF window icon does not show up in taskbar

Tags: c#, wpf, mfc, windows-10, taskbar

I have an MFC window-based app. I added a C# class library that provides a second window for login to the app. This second window is meant to show before the main MFC window and once the user successfully logs in, it will go away and the main window will launch. The problem I am having is that when the login window is showing there is no taskbar icon for it. This did work correctly when the login window was an MFC dialog.

To make debugging this window easier I made a small MFC test app from which I can launch the login window with a button click. (the main program is cumbersome to test with). I added a C# class library to it just as it is in the main program. When I launch the app the main MFC dialog app shows up and the app's icon appears on the taskbar. When I click the button to launch the WPF window, it appears but there is no icon in the taskbar. This window does not show on the taskbar as a second window of the app as I would expect.

- I am having a really hard time with google finding **relevant** info.
- I have tried specifying an icon for the window vs. not specifying one.
- I have tried adding `ShowInTaskbar="True"` to the window.
- I have tried changing `WindowStyle`
- I have tried playing with `TaskbarItemInfo`.
- I tried following [New taskbar icon when opening a window in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337717/new-taskbar-icon-when-opening-a-window-in-wpf), but I don't really understand it well enough to say that it will fix my issue since I do not get my window showing up at all and if I did I would be fine with it being stacked.

I am not sure where else to go with this. Please let me know if there is anything unclear.